# multiple cgroups within "blkio" susbsytem for lxc container

Tags: lxc

I created a privileged `lxc` container on ubuntu 16.0.4LTS with name `mk7i_container`.

When I looked at the `blkio` cgroup of `lxc`, I found the following entries:

```
manik@manik:/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/lxc$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 .
dr-xr-xr-x  6 root root 0 Sep 22 11:38 ..
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.io_merged
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.io_merged_recursive
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.io_queued
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.io_queued_recursive
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.io_service_bytes
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.io_service_bytes_recursive
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.io_serviced
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.io_serviced_recursive
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.io_service_time
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.io_service_time_recursive
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.io_wait_time
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.io_wait_time_recursive
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.leaf_weight
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.leaf_weight_device
--w-------  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.reset_stats
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.sectors
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.sectors_recursive
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.throttle.io_service_bytes
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.throttle.io_serviced
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.throttle.read_bps_device
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.throttle.read_iops_device
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.throttle.write_bps_device
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.throttle.write_iops_device
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.time
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.time_recursive
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.weight
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 blkio.weight_device
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 cgroup.clone_children
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 cgroup.procs
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container-1
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container-2
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container-3
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container-4
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container-5
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container-6
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container-7
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container-8
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 notify_on_release
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 tasks
```

I don't understand why there are multiple entries for `mk7i_container`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container-1
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container-2
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container-3
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container-4
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container-5
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container-6
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container-7
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Sep 22 13:37 mk7i_container-8
```

anyone know why ?